# Django Writtable Nested Serializers - Error NOT NULL Constraints

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a "Prospect" object, which is nested under my "Appointment" serializer. But when posting, I keep getting the error "*NOT NULL constraint failed: schedule_appointment.prospect_id*".

I suppose Django is expecting me to pass a prospect_id when posting, but how do I go about doing this? I've read elsewhere that an alternative is to set the foreign key to null=True, but in my case, an Appointment MUST have a Prospect.

Any suggestions?

**Serializers**

```
class ProspectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Prospect
        fields = [  'id','first_name', 'last_name', 'email']


class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prospect = ProspectSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ['appointment_time', 'unit', 'staff', 'prospect']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        prospect_data = validated_data.pop('prospect')
        appointment = Appointment.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Prospect.objects.create(appointment=appointment, **prospect_data)
        return appointment
```

**Models**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointment_time = models.DateTimeField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prospect = models.ForeignKey(Prospect, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Prospect(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need create Prospect model and then Appointment

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        prospect_data = validated_data.pop('prospect')
        prospect = Prospect.objects.create(**prospect_data)
        appointment = Appointment.objects.create(prospect=prospect, **validated_data)

        return appointment
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! Can't believe I didn't see this... Thank you very much :)